# Android: java.lang.SecurityException - despite having declared <uses-permission>

Tags: android

I'm getting some SecurityException's in my app, presumably due to missing permissions. It happens very rarely and doesn't seem to be consistent, kind of a 'once in a blue moon' thing. I haven't got access to any of the devices that it's crashed on. It seems to happen across different manufacturer, and android versions.

What i've done so far, is check my `AndroidManifest.xml` for `<uses-permission>` and that it's in the right scope, as an immediate child of `<mainfest>` and everything seems fine. Below is my AndroidManifest.xml - shortened a bit for readability. And i've tried to google it, and I've found a similare issue on Google Groups, which also seems to be unsolved: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-c2dm/QIjbqO38rHI

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.eTilbudsavis.eTilbudsavis" >

    <!-- SOME PERMISSIONS E.T.C. REMOVED FOR READABILITY -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- THE PERMISSION'S THAT CAUSES CRASHES -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <permission
        android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.eTilbudsavis.eTilbudsavis.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_app"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.eTilbudsavis.eTilbudsavis.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.eTilbudsavis.eTilbudsavis.test.TestActivity" >
        </activity>

        <!-- ACTIVITIES, SERVICES, RECIEVERS REMOVED FOR READABILITY -->

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I've included a couple of stack traces, that I have from out crash reporter along with device info.

The first missing `com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE` which is in the manifest. Devices: Sony Xperia Z1 Compact (D5503, running android 5.0.2) and Samsung Galaxy S III (I9300, running Android 4.3).

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms (has extras) } without permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
       at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1730)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1707)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:515)
       at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.zzs()
       at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register()
       at com.eTilbudsavis.eTilbudsavis.notification.GcmRegistration.run(GcmRegistration.java:42)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Second one is missing `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`, which is also defined in the mainfest. Devices: Huawei Ascend P7 (P7-L10, running Android 4.4.2)

```
java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10184 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1475)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1429)
       at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:843)
       at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:635)
       at com.eTilbudsavis.eTilbudsavis.ConnectionChecker.isOnline(ConnectionChecker.java:67)
       at com.eTilbudsavis.eTilbudsavis.ConnectionChecker.run(ConnectionChecker.java:42)
```

Third one Second one is missing `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, which is also defined in the mainfest. Devices: Samsung Galaxy Tab S 8.4 (SM-T705, running Android 4.4.2)

```
java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.t.a()
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.ft.a()
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.aj.a()
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.ai.a()
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.x.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView()
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView()
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb()
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza()
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView()
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView()
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
       at com.eTilbudsavis.eTilbudsavis.fragment.LocationMapFragment.ensureSupportMapFragment(LocationMapFragment.java:338)
       at com.eTilbudsavis.eTilbudsavis.fragment.LocationMapFragment.onStart(LocationMapFragment.java:676)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1813)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:989)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The issue seems to have magically solved it self. Last crash i've registered was in august 2015. I haven't changed any code regarding this error, and I still have no idea what was the cause of this.

Comment: have you ever find and solutions about this? thanks.